# Running a script every time I switch between apps on OS X

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, window-manager

Is there a way I can run a script (either bash or AppleScript) every time I switch between apps? Switching between windows is also acceptable. I checked Automator but I could not find it.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to track time spent in various applications, there are applications for this :-)

Comment: nope, I'm trying to send messages to my Keyboardio Model 01 so that it plays different macros based on the app I'm using. I know there is a way to do application based shortcuts but it wouldn't work with the function key since OS X wouldn't detect function key presses

Comment: Maybe add this to the question so people understand the problem you want to solve here.

Comment: For anyone curious, I couldn't find a way so I ended up forking/writing a small app runs in the background all the time and listens to window change notifications: https://github.com/joom/WindowWatcher